# Grep command- How to use in different directories

Tags: linux

How to grep single word in different directory and file name is also same in different directory.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure to understand what you want.

Can't you just run

```
  grep -rwn word /some/dir1/ /other/dir2/
```

Read the [GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) documentation!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using bash you can use the following:

```
grep 'pattern' {dir1,dir2,dir3}/filename
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify each file as an argument:

```
grep -w vwhat /some/file /another/file /a/third/file
```